# Conditions with comparison operators and numbers only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, numbers, conditional-operator

I would like a user to input a number. If number is between 1 and 100, I would alert with message "Great". If input is below 1 and more than 100, I would alert "Please, only numbers between 1-100.
I am having two problems here:

1. My conditions with comparison operators do not work. No matter what number I enter more than 100 or less than 100, I still get the same message. I just wonder if someone could point where is the error.
2. The second problem is that I can even enter letters. When I enter letters, it just goes to the second alert message "Please, only numbers from 1-100".

What is the easiest way to make user to enter numbers only, not letters or other symbols, and alert them to enter only digits.

```
 var userInput = prompt('Enter a number'); // asking user to input a number

  if (userInput<=100 || userInput>=1) {
  alert ('Great !');}
if(userInput <1 && userInput > 100);
{
  alert('Please, only numbers betwen 1-100'); }
```

Comment: *"If user input is below 1 __and__ over 100"* — It cannot be both those things at the same time.

Comment: userInput cannot be < 1 and > 100 at the same time. The second if has a ; before the open bracket

Comment: *"If user input is under 100 __or__ over 1"* — Every number is either below hundred or over 1…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A prompt box is always a string input and you can't change that into numerical. If you want just numerical input, you can use `<input type="number" />`. But with a prompt box you can write a code that if the user input wasn't a number, it alerts **Input was not a number** and asks for input again. Also, you had a mistake in your code. A number cannot be less than 1 **and** greater than 100. So in the end, your code will look like this.

```
function getusrin() {
    var usrin = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number : ", "1"));
    while (isNaN(usrin)) {
        alert("Input was not a number");
        usrin = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number : ", "1"));
    }
    return usrin;
}
var usrin = getusrin();
while (usrin < 1 || usrin > 100) {
    alert("Please, only numbers betwen 1-100");
    usrin = getusrin();
}
alert("Great!");
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept and/or upvote that. Also, you can click on the clapping icon below the voting to say thanks to me. Please don't say thanks in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this

```
const userInput = prompt('Enter a number')

if (userInput >= 1 && userInput <= 100) {
    alert('Great!')
} else {
    alert('Please, only numbers betwen 1-100')
}
```